# Store data in session for the dynamically created HTMLAnchor tag

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application , I have created HTMLAnchor class and HTMLImage class dynamically.
So that they bind the data from sqlserver at runtime. The code as below,

```
for (int i = 0; i < _dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              //Allows programmatic access to the HTML <a> element on the server.
              HtmlAnchor URL = new HtmlAnchor();
              URL.HRef = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MakerURL"].ToString();
              URL.Attributes.Add("col-md-2 select_make", "url");
              URL.Target = "_self";
              URL.InnerText = "";

              //Allows programmatic access to the HTML <img> element on the server.
              HtmlImage htmlImage = new HtmlImage();
              htmlImage.Src = _dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();

              //add htmlimage control to anchor control
              URL.Controls.Add(htmlImage);
              //add anchor control to div control
              makeList.Controls.Add(URL);
          }
```

So far so good!. Everything works fine. Now my requirement is when i click on image it redirect to another page where i need to show the image which i selected from home page.
How do i proceed with my above code.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Is the image inside the Anchor tag?

Comment: @Simua: Yes the image tag is inside anchor tag.

Comment: What .net framework version are you using and are you using a FormView or Details View?

Comment: @Simua: Using 4.5 version. No FormView or details view is used.

Comment: If I may ask, do you have a specific reason for not using Formview, detailsview or the likes of such?

Comment: You could use a repeater control and bind your dataTable to it. This makes it very easy for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may append the Id or name of image as query string in href of anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the PageLoad of CodeBehind of target page:

```
HtmlImage htmlImage = new HtmlImage();
htmlImage.Src = _dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
//add htmlimage control to anchor control
Page.Controls.Add(htmlImage);
or
AnyOtherControlInYourPage.Controls.Add(htmlImage);
```

Comment: I think i managed to acheive it. By passing the query string to url. Thank you for the responses.